# Cannot replace default icon in android studio

Tags: android, file, android-studio, icons

The image I am trying to replace the default icon with is 512x512px .png.
To change the icon I go app/res [new; image asset;...].
It won't let me replace or create new icon set in the @drawable.
My most recent thought are that I might not have unlocked some priveges but I am able edit contents of drawable by directly accessing it's location

Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have refreshed, synchronized, rebuilt, cleaned and restarted the project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version of android studio put default launcher icon(ic_launcher.png) in mipmap-xxx directories, so just copy and paste your new icon to these directores, and reference it as '@mipmap/you_icon', or in code 'R.mipmap.you_icon'. If you still want to use the keyword 'drawable', then create the drawable folders(drawable-xxx), and put your icon there, and reference it as '@drawable/you_icon', or in code 'R.drawable.you_icon'

Comment: Thank you @wrkwrk. In reality what happened was that the android studio didnt change the @drawable/ folder as I updated the icon resource. But the @mipmap/ was updated. The manifest didn't recognise the change because the source for icons was set to drawable android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" so  I had to change it to android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher".

Comment: I'm using android studio 1.2.1.1 on wndows, In my case, I created a folder named 'drawable-xhdpi' under res/, and put an icon in it, android studio recognised it properly, I could set the icon as imageview src using android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Answer (score 5):

Place your icon in the drawable folder and then simply open your AndroidManifest.xml file and then set the icon you want like this ...

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    .... >
```

Answer (score 0):

As what you wrote

> app/res [new; image asset;...]

You mean this one on the image right? What specific error does it shows?
just make sure that your icon name is the same in the manifest `android:icon="@mipmap/youricon"`

[image: Asset Studio]

Comment: Thank you @Emmanuel You are right I did't change the android:icon="@drawable/youricon" to android:icon="@mipmap/youricon"

Comment: yay! if you're glad with this answer you could mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

step 1. copy the icon image from mipmap to drawable folders and build your project.

step 2. Change the following code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```