# Can't change icon for my android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Firstly, I copied some icon to `mipmap`(named ic_launcher.png) - Didn't work.

Second I right clicked `res>new>image asset` - Didn't work too.

My manifest.xml code is as.

```
 <application
    android:name=".BlogI"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/applicationicon"  // This even shows the right icon in right corner along with the line numbers
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ......
    ......
```

I tried clean project and rerun, restarted my android studio(even my PC) also restarted my android device. But, none of the above worked. Before asking this question I tried other similar questions but none helped.
 [Like this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563900/cannot-replace-default-icon-in-android-studio)

If there are any alternatives them please do suggest ! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the app and re-run it?

Comment: how many mipmap folders do you have? make sure you changed for all devices if you have more than 1

Comment: @PrerakSola Yeap tried that. More than seven times now. Didn't work.

Comment: Try it on a different device/emulator.

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic there are 5 mipmap folders. I changed for all. Not working.

Comment: Did you try changing android:icon="@mipmap/applicationicon" to android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" ?

Comment: do you have different builds (debug/normal) in gradle settings?

Comment: @PrerakSola I tried this on 4 devices. 2 of them showed the proper icon but other 2 didn't.  Thanks. I'll try to figure out the rest.

Comment: @FabriPautasso Sorry didn't work.

Comment: Try to uninstall the app, clean the device's cache, clean Android Studio's cache (File -> Invalidate cache and Restart) and try after that.

Comment: @PrerakSola tried it before ,didn't work.

Comment: Can you try placing this in the drawable folder and then call android:icon="@drawable/applicationicon"

Comment: @AnuragJoshi nope tried that didn't work.

Comment: open R.java and check inside drawable inner class whether there is any field with your icon id and paste your manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the fix! It was my 3rd party launcher `(Evie Launcher)`  that didn't update the icons. The icons worked fine on all the devices here on including mine after I changed my launcher.

Thanks for all the suggestions and answers.

Comment: LOL very interesting

Comment: I get the same problem and the same solution. How does it work

Answer (score 4):

When you generate image asset, **delete** `ic_launcher.xml` but **keep** the `png` files. xml file has ic_launcher_foreground attribute that overrides default android launcher icon.

Comment: When VS created the app from the template it created this directory:  Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26    The xml file was in there.  I deleted that and the new icon displayed fine.  Thx @Ege

Answer (score 1):

First paste your image in `drawable` then add following code in `manifest.xml`

```
 <application
        android:name=".BlogI"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/your_Image"
        android:label="@string/app_name">`
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work! If it was this small error I guess I would have fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the mistake I was doing from long time.

Just make sure that in `AndroidMainfest.xml` you have set both properties - `android:icon` and `android:roundIcon` appropriately

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon".../>
```

I was just setting `android:icon` and kept `android:roundIcon` unchanged.